# How do I save a Save/Load a text file in Red

Tags: red

I already know how to do this, but I figured I would go ahead and ask since the Rebol documentation is offline today and so in the future others will have an easier time finding out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, use `read` for reading a text file (a string will be returned) and `write` for writing a string down to a file. For example:

```
write %hello.txt "Hello World!"
print read %hello.txt
```

Such text-mode I/O relies on UTF-8 for reading/writing, other encodings will be supported in the future.

Additionally, you can use `/binary` refinement for both functions to switch to binary mode. You can also use the higher-level `load` and `save` counterparts, which will try to encode/decode the data using one of the available codecs (UTF-8 <=> Red values, JPG/PNG/GIF/BMP <=> `image!` value).

Use `help` followed by a function name for more info.